# Call only one method from methods

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

On this example, I change the "`name`" via the method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#exercise',
  data: {
    name: 'Petr',
  },
  methods: {
    random: function() {
      return Math.random();
    },
    changeName: function(event) {
      this.name = event.target.value;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="exercise">
  <p>VueJS is pretty cool - {{ name }}</p>
  <p>{{ random() }}</p>
  <div>
    <input v-on:input="changeName" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

But each time I call the method `changeName` the other method (`random`) also is called.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Computed Properties - Computed Caching vs Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods):

> In comparison, a method invocation will always run the function whenever a re-render happens.

And **when does a re-render happen**? When data changes.

And in your example data (i.e. `name`) changes whenever you type into the `<input>` (because it calls `changeName`).

Check the [lifecycle diagram](http://%20https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) - more specifically, the "Mounted" red ball:

[image: vue.js 2 lifecycle diagram]

Check the demo below, so you see those lifecycle events are happening (and thus the re-rendering between them):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#exercise',
  data: {
    name: 'Petr',
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    console.log('beforeUpdate executed');
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('updated executed');
  },
  methods: {
    random: function() {
      return Math.random();
    },
    changeName: function(event) {
      this.name = event.target.value;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="exercise">
  <p>VueJS is pretty cool - {{ name }}</p>
  <p>{{ random() }}</p>
  <div>
    <input v-on:input="changeName" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@acdcjunior explained it very well about this issue:

> In comparison, a method invocation will always run the function whenever a re-render happens.

But what if you really want to bind the random method when you really want? Here's the solution:

**Modified HTML**

```
<div id="exercise">
  <p>VueJS is pretty cool - {{ name }}</p>
  <p>{{ randomNumber }}</p>
  <div>
    <input v-on:input="changeName" type="text">
    <input type="button" @click="random" value="Generate Random Number">
  </div>
</div>
```

In the preceding example, we are using data `randomNumber`. I have added a button that holds the `random` method to generate a random number when we click on it.

```
// modified data option:
data: {
  name: 'Petr',
  randomNumber: '' /* initialize randomNumber */
},
// modified random method
methods: {
  random: function() {
    /* Now, we return data randomNumber */
    return this.randomNumber = Math.random();
  },
  changeName: function(event) {
    this.name = event.target.value;
  }
},
created() {
  // we need to show random number when instance is created
  this.random();
}
```

What the heck is happening here? The method `random` should be invoked and the random number should also be generated, right?

No. The method `random` isn't invoked because we've not used this method anywhere ie. not bound `random()` in our template binding.

So, what it means is that, the method is only invoked (after re-render as being said) if there is the method hooked somewhere inside our template.