# Why vue js triggers all methods when there is a change in data?

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.3, vue-directives

I have a input field in the form to get the customer name and binding the value to model "customer_name".

```
<input placeholder="Customer name" required="required" name="customer_name" type="text" id="customer_name" class="form-control" v-model="customer_name">
```

If user submits the form, I am making a ajax get request to get the matching customer names and storing the results in the variable "customers" and rending the results in table view.

```
<tr v-for="customer in customers">
    <td >
        @{{ customer.firstname + " " +customer.lastname}}
    </td>
    <td >
        @{{ formatBday(customer.birthday)}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is formatBday() implementation,

```
methods: {
    formatBday : function (bday) {
        console.log("function called");
        return moment(bday).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
    }
}
```

So after every ajax call, it will show the results in table view. After showing the results, now i am trying to change the value in customer name text box, and i have observed, for every character i type in the customer name textbox, formatBday() function is being executed.

There is no binding between customername textbox and formatBday() function. But after the search, whenever i type/change customer name formatBday() is being triggered.

Does anyone know how to stop this unwanted function triggering?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130636/call-only-one-method-from-methods

Comment: Thanks, now i understand how the lifecycle works. But how can i make the function call triggers only after there is a change in "customers" variable. Yes, I can use computed property but "customers" is a json object. How can i set computed property in a specific attribute inside json object?

Comment: You can't, it watches only the whole object. If you are changing some value inside `customers`, you could copy that value in other property (in `data`), edit that other property only, and when it is done you go and replace the value in `customers` with this new value you edited (so the `customers` only changes once, at the end). But, you see, this makes your code considerably more complicated. I would only do it if the problem you are facing is provoking some real performance issues.

Comment: I solved the issue based on your comments, thanks. What I have done is, I splitted the customers in to individual customer component and attached computed properties in component. Now the issue solved.

Comment: additionally, you should use filters for "formatBDay" method.